# How to handle the .msi file with Inno Setup?

Tags: installation, inno-setup

I have this following code with Inno Setup.

But how can I apply this similar function to .msi file?

`msiexec /I "\package\file.msi" /qb`? How?

```pascal
procedure AfterMyProgInstall(S: String);
var
  ErrorCode: Integer;
begin
  {MsgBox('Please wait the libraries are getting installed, ' +
          'without the libraries it wont work.', mbInformation, MB_OK);}
  ExtractTemporaryFile(S);
  {SW_SHOW, SW_SHOWNORMAL, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED, SW_SHOWMINIMIZED, SW_SHOWMINNOACTIVE, SW_HIDE}
  ShellExec('', ExpandConstant('{app}\package\' + S), '', '', SW_SHOWNORMAL,
            ewWaitUntilTerminated, ErrorCode);
end;
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try this:

```pascal
ShellExec('', 'msiexec.exe',
  ExpandConstant('/I "{tmp}\package\file.msi" /qb'),
  '', SW_SHOWNORMAL, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ErrorCode);
```

Or:

```
[Files]
Source: file.msi; DestDir: {tmp}; Flags: deleteafterinstall;

[Run]
Filename: "msiexec.exe"; Parameters: "/i ""{tmp}\file.msi"" /qb"; WorkingDir: {tmp};
```

Comment: Is there any way to automatically uninstall the msi as part of the innosetup uninstall routine though?

Comment: Alternatively, use the shellexec flag: `Filename: "{tmp}\file.msi"; Parameters: "/qb"; Flags: shellexec `

Answer (score 4):

**Note** that: I'm using Inno Setup 5.5.3 on Windows 7, and that this code
is for the Inno Setup script in the run section. With this code you can
run `msi` files without any problems. Here is the code:

```
[Run]
Filename: `{src}\PhysX.msi;` Description: Nvidia PhysX; Verb: open; Flags: shellexec postinstall waituntilterminated runascurrentuser skipifsilent
```

Answer (score 4):

Building on the answer @kobik gave. I had to include the '.exe' in the Filename. 
Like so:

```pascal
if not ShellExec('', 'msiexec.exe', ExpandConstant('{tmp}\package\file.msi'),
  '', SW_SHOWNORMAL, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ErrorCode)
then
  MsgBox('Msi installer failed to run!' + #13#10 + ' ' +
    SysErrorMessage(ErrorCode), mbError, MB_OK);
```

Comment: @mike, obviously kobik "didn't show the whole code". This is at most a comment... Besides, wouldn't be better to let the Windows Shell open the file by itself ? I mean, just passing the MSI package filename to the `Filename` parameter. Shell will handle this if Windows Installer is installed and MSI packages are registered to be executed by it.

Comment: @TLama thanks for helping me with stackoverflow contribution culture, I'm a noob. Could you clarify if this discussion belongs in comments or in a "meta" area of the site. 

re: Your alternate suggestion, I don't understand it; please provide an example. I posted code that I found to work, I hope it helps others. Specifically, "Windows Installer is installed and MSI packages are registered to be executed by it." How do I know if this is true on my system?

Comment: @mike, no worries. Keep your answer here as it might add an important detail to the accepted answer (just let me correct one thing...). About opening MSI file, I meant to do it [`this way`](http://pastebin.com/e30VMqPp). But haven't tried it (yet).

Comment: @TLama Just figured out why I couldn't do a comment. I do not have the reputation score to do so.

Comment: @mike, yes, it's a pity that commenting was abused in the past so there are those reputation limits set even for people who are just trying to help. I hope you'll raise your reputation soon so you'll get removed all the "annoying" restrictions. Good luck and welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 2):

Although kobik's option to use "msiexec.exe /i" in Run section generally works, we faced a  problem of admin right downgrade with it:

```
[Run]
Filename: "msiexec.exe"; Parameters: "/i ""{tmp}\file.msi"" /qb"; WorkingDir: {tmp};
```

When msiexec.exe /i file.msi runs this way it requests the admin rights with UAC (as expected, it is really required in our case). But somewhere in the middle of this installation part when "file.msi" is trying to start a windows service it appeared to be right-downgraded and have not enough privileges to start windows service.
However when it's launched via shellexec it goes ok without this problem. So this is how it worked to me:

```
[Run]
Filename: "{tmp}\file.msi"; Flags: skipifsilent shellexec waituntilterminated hidewizard;
```

Comment: I got the same permissions problem, the even after using shellexec, still gives the same error.   `Filename: "{tmp}\file.msi"; Parameters: "/qb"; Flags: shellexec waituntilterminated ; WorkingDir: {tmp};`